# Java overload on different parameter type (numeric) but same algorithm

Tags: java

I'm currently has several methods to compare two numbers.
They are exact same algorithm, just different parameter types.
However, overloading seems too many copy paste.

Current code :

```java
    private boolean isFieldUpdateAllowed(float existingData, float submittedData) {
        if (existingData > 0 && submittedData <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (existingData <= 0 && submittedData > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        if (existingData > 0 && submittedData > 0 && existingData != submittedData) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isFieldUpdateAllowed(int existingData, int submittedData) {
        if (existingData > 0 && submittedData <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (existingData <= 0 && submittedData > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        if (existingData > 0 && submittedData > 0 && existingData != submittedData) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

// other numeric type comparison
```

Any way to simplify the code?

Comment: Looks like a good use-case for [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Looks like you don't need the different signatures in the first place. Why not just use a broader data type (like `double`) and get rid of the overload altogether?

Comment: Can't edit my comment above, but I forgot to say that generics would be useful if you want to compare `Comparable`s. If it's just numbers, yeah, what ernest_k said.

Comment: ah yes, silly me... thanks. Using double is good

Answer (score 0):

> ah yes, silly me... thanks. Using `double` is good.

No. Wait.  Not so fast.

For the integral types, yes, you can replace all of the overloads with a method with `long` argument types.  Other integral types can all be converted to `long` without any loss of information, and the comparisons will work as expected.

But there is a gotcha when we get to `double`.

The problem is that a `double` only has 53 binary bits of precision.  So when you convert a large enough `long` value to a `double` you get a number that is not *mathematically* equal to the original value.

So when compare this:

```
    if (existingData > 0 && submittedData > 0 && existingData != submittedData) {
        return true;
    }
```

in the `long` and `double` cases, for some argument values, the `!=` test with `long` values will be `true`, but with the converted `double` values it will be `false` ... because of the loss of precision in the conversion.

In short, you have to have overloads for both `long` and `double`, or you risk getting incorrect results in some cases.